# CSS Class Reverts to Not Active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am adding a class to an image.

```
.bbbLink img { 
    outline: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

On hover I add this,

```
.bbbLink img:hover { 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    outline: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
}
```

For active I am doing this,

```
.bbbLink img:active {
    outline: 1px solid #111 !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #555 !important;
    padding: 10px !important;
    background: #333 !important;
}
```

Since I am adding the active class to an image and you cannot do this because it is a self closing element I am using jquery to handle adding the active state like this,

```
<script>
(function($) {
$('.bbbLink').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
})( jQuery );
</script>
```

Everything works perfectly, even when checking the dom after clicking the element my active class appears.

```
<a id="wrapbbb" class="bbbLink active" href="img.jpg" target="_blank">
<img src="content/uploads/-2-018.jpg" alt="BBB">
</a>
```

The problem is that when I press the mouse down and click, active state shows and the styling takes effect but when I release the click the active state styling goes away...

The active class is still in the dom but the styling effects revert back to the class without the active state.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Er... You need to give CSS like this:

```
.bbbLink img.active {
```

When you have `:active`, it is a state, active / mousedown state, not a class. Hope this is not a typo.

Comment: Ok so my problem here is my jquery is not doing what I thought it was doing. Thank you for your help. So basically if I want to add an active state I need to change my jquery to add active to a class? Or just swap the class out instead because its an image?

Comment: @NichoDiaz Your question is confusing. What you have given the browser to do in CSS is, when I am putting my mouse clicked, do what I like, and **not** when the class is added, do what I like. Do you understand the difference? So adding classes is the best. `:)` Using `:active` is worst! `:P`

Comment: I would definitely recommend swapping the classes rather than using the active logic.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar I get what you guys are saying. Would one of you show me how to swap the class instead of adding it with jquery?

Comment: Like what you are doing is fine. Just apply the answer in your code.